Why is the base of the exponential function in the softmax formula chosen as e, rather than 2 or other numbers?
I have been studying the softmax function, and I am curious why the natural constant $e$ is used as the base of the exponential function in the softmax formula. Specifically, I would like to understand why $e$ is preferred over other numbers, such as 2, or arbitrary constants.
I understand that $e$ has special properties in calculus, particularly the fact that $ \frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$, which simplifies derivative calculations. However, I would appreciate a deeper explanation of its origin and how it relates to the overall performance and stability of the softmax function, especially in the context of machine learning and optimization.
Additionally, I am interested in how the choice of $e$ connects to probability distributions and why this choice ensures the softmax output is a valid probability distribution. Is there a historical or theoretical reason for choosing $e$, perhaps linked to information theory or gradient-based optimization?
Thank you for your help in advance.

If you didn't use $e$, you would have a bunch of logarithms floating around in all your integral and derivative formulas. That's really all it is

The choice of $e$ as the base of the exponentiation in the softmax function is simply because $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \ln a$, where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm (i.e. base $e$), and so setting $a = e$ means that when taking derivatives you don't have any messy $\ln a$ terms in your expressions.
It certainly doesn't affect the function's use as a probability distribution - that's the result of the normalisation factor $\frac{1}{\sum \exp(z_j)}$.  Essentially for any vector of non-negative (and not all zero) values, if you divide it by the sum of its components then the resulting vector will have a sum of 1, which results in a valid discrete probability distribution.
